# Extract log file entries for a specific date

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have a shell history that appears in this format:

```
361     2017/08/22 10:50:37 :: df -k .
362     2017/08/22 10:50:41 :: df -gt .
363     2017/08/22 10:50:54 :: while true
        do
        df -gt .
        sleep 5
        done
364     2017/08/22 10:51:15 :: while true
        do
        df -kt .
        sleep 10
        done
365     2017/08/22 11:00:59 :: bffcreate -d /mnt/loopmount2 -t /SOFTWARE/AIX71TL4SP4 all
366     2017/08/22 11:06:31 :: alog -L
367     2017/08/22 11:06:46 :: alog -L boot -o
368     2017/08/22 11:08:01 :: alog -f /var/adm/ras/bootlog -o
369     2017/08/22 11:08:49 :: alog -f /var/adm/ras/bootlog -o > /tmp/1
370     2017/08/22 11:08:58 :: alog -o -t boot > /tmp/2
```

I want to capture all the commands specific to a 2017/08/22 and save it to a file. But if I use grep, I am not able to capture those commands that stretch for several lines but have no date column after their starting line.

```
Eg. Rows 363 and 364 contains while statements but grep is not able to capture the entire statement.

# history -t -9999 | grep "2017/08/22"
...
360     2017/08/22 10:50:11 :: oslevel -sq
361     2017/08/22 10:50:37 :: df -k .
362     2017/08/22 10:50:41 :: df -gt .
363     2017/08/22 10:50:54 :: while true
364     2017/08/22 10:51:15 :: while true
365     2017/08/22 11:00:59 :: bffcreate -d /mnt/loopmount2 -t /SOFTWARE/AIX71TL4SP4 all
366     2017/08/22 11:06:31 :: alog -L
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with **awk**:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/2017\/08\/22/{ p=1 }
/^[0-9]+/ && $2!~/2017\/08\/22/{ p=0; next }
p
```

running:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
361     2017/08/22 10:50:37 :: df -k .
362     2017/08/22 10:50:41 :: df -gt .
363     2017/08/22 10:50:54 :: while true
        do
        df -gt .
        sleep 5
        done
364     2017/08/22 10:51:15 :: while true
        do
        df -kt .
        sleep 10
        done
365     2017/08/22 11:00:59 :: bffcreate -d /mnt/loopmount2 -t /SOFTWARE/AIX71TL4SP4 all
366     2017/08/22 11:06:31 :: alog -L
367     2017/08/22 11:06:46 :: alog -L boot -o
368     2017/08/22 11:08:01 :: alog -f /var/adm/ras/bootlog -o
369     2017/08/22 11:08:49 :: alog -f /var/adm/ras/bootlog -o > /tmp/1
370     2017/08/22 11:08:58 :: alog -o -t boot > /tmp/2
```

or commandline:

```
$ awk '/2017\/08\/22/{ p=1 } /^[0-9]+/ && $2!~/2017\/08\/22/{ p=0; next }p' input.txt
```

Suppose you wanted to use the date as an inputvariable, you can match agains a variable without using the // markers. A slight change to the commandline gives you:

```
$ awk -v d='2017/08/22' '$2~d{p=1} /^[0-9]+/ && $2!~d{p=0; next}p' input.txt
```

Comment: That matches additional lines at the end, too (that are not part of the input above, but I assume they exist).

Comment: You're right. Mindset on python. Regexes incorrect.

Comment: Works now. Nice!

Comment: Thanks! If I want to substitute the date as a variable into the awk statement, whats the syntax for that?

Comment: Something like $ awk -v d='2017/08/22' '$2~d{p=1} /^[0-9]+/ && $2!~d{p=0; next}p' input.txt

Comment: how does the "/^[0-9]+/" part of the awk statement work in capturing the lines that do not have $2~d match but are within the range?

Comment: `/^[0-9]+/` matches those lines that start with a number. `/^[0-9]+/ && $2!~d` matches those lines, that start with a number and have a different date in column 2 (different from param d).